# Excel MINUTE function returns 0:00

Tags: excel, xls, minute

When I use the MINUTE() Function in excel, instead of the minutes being returned it always returns 0:00:00, any idea why this occurs?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the value in P5?

Comment: its 10:10, I changed the format to number and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your formatting to be a number.

`=MINUTE(10/60/24)` returns `10`.

Any whole number is equivalent to midnight on some date.

Converted to a time format, every whole number appears as ”0:00:00”